# How to minimize SQL query to give output very fast?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries from which I have created one which is giving me full data, but the issue is that it is taking so much time to execute.

There are several cases I am using because of that it is taking so much of time, I just want to know can I minimize it further so that it will not effect my output but execute faster.

**Query1**

```
select outlet, sum(netamount) 
from syncbill 
where cancelled<>'Y' 
and year(curdate())=year(billdate) 
and month(curdate())=month(billdate) 
group by OUTLET;
```

**Query2**

```
select outlet,sum(netamount) 
from syncbill 
where cancelled<>'Y' 
and year(curdate())=year(billdate) 
group by OUTLET;
```

I am merging the above two queries to get result in one go

**new query**

```
select  b.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR as outlet,
        round(sum(case when year(curdate())=year(a.billdate) and month(curdate())=month(a.billdate) then a.netamount else 0 end)) as monthAmount, 
        ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 9 MONTH) = YEAR(billdate + INTERVAL 9 MONTH) THEN netamount ELSE 0 END)) as yearAmount , 
        round(Sum(case when a.billdate >= date(now()) then a.netamount else 0 end)) as Transaction
from syncbill a Inner Join
     ecustomer b
     on a.outlet = b.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER 
where a.cancelled <> 'Y' and
      outlet in (select CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER from mt_distributrol where mt_distributr_vcdistributrcode = 'AAAA')
group by a.OUTLET
```

What I am doing in the above query is

Calculating current month data and current year(financial year) data if there is data then data else `0`.

But it is taking so much of time which is appearing as very bad user experience. How can I minimize this?

### Edit

I have made a new query after creating indexes, but query is showing error. Here is my query:

`select outlet,round(sum(case when year(curdate())=year(billdate) and month(curdate())=month(billdate) then netamount else 0 end)) as monthAmount, ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 9 MONTH) = YEAR(billdate + INTERVAL 9 MONTH) THEN netamount ELSE 0 END)) as yearAmount , round(Sum(case when billdate >= date(now()) then netamount else 0 end)) as Transaction from  syncbill  where cancelled<>'Y' and force index (ix_cancelled, ix_outlet) and force INDEX (ix_outlet) FOR group by  OUTLET`

This is the error I am getting

**query with force**

```
select  b.CUSTOMERDESCRIPTOR as outlet,round(sum(case when year(curdate())=year(a.billdate) and month(curdate())=month(a.billdate) then a.netamount else 0 end)) as monthAmount, ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 9 MONTH) = YEAR(billdate + INTERVAL 9 MONTH) THEN netamount ELSE 0 END)) as yearAmount , round(Sum(case when a.billdate >= date(now()) then a.netamount else 0 end)) as Transaction from  syncbill a force index (ix_cancelled_OUTLET_billdate) Inner Join ecustomer b on a.outlet = b.CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER where    a.cancelled<>'Y' and  outlet in(select CUSTOMERIDENTIFIER from mt_distributrol where mt_distributr_vcdistributrcode = 'AAAA')  group by   a.OUTLET
```

[image: error I am getting from new query after creating indexes]

[image: final query result]

[image: after running the query with explain]

[image: table structure in database]

Comment: How `EXPLAIN` output looks like?

Comment: Please share more context about the table structure, sample data, and the indices you are currently using

Comment: @rkosegi i have attached two images

Comment: Please don't share sample data in images. Nobody wants to read them into a database to test solutions. Additionally, where's the output of `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: `EXPLAIN` i didn't get you sir?

Comment: `EXPLAIN` will show you which indices are used - so you can check **why** a query runs slow. If you have not heard about that yet, please google it, that will provide useful insights

Comment: @NicoHaase i have updated the post with explain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188207/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-nico-haase).

Comment: Please don't add images of everything - post the `EXPLAIN` output in text form. Additionally, which types of indices have you considered yet? According to the `EXPLAIN`, none is used so far

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  You have two queries that you want to combine and they reference only one tables.  Then you combine them and new tables mysteriously appear.  The question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the one final query is taking too much time to execute

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a couple of indexes:
one on 'outlet' for the group by and one on cancelled to improve the filter.

```
CREATE  INDEX ix_outlet ON syncbill(outlet);
```

and

```
CREATE  INDEX ix_cancelled ON syncbill(cancelled);
```

then force mysql to use those

```
select a,b,c
from my_table
force index (ix_cancelled, ix_outlet)
force INDEX (ix_outlet) FOR GROUP BY
where a = condition_1
group by a,b
```

Comment: will this improve the output speed?

Comment: It will improve query speed so also output will begin earlier

Comment: hey `select outlet,round(sum(case when year(curdate())=year(billdate) and month(curdate())=month(billdate) then netamount else 0 end)) as monthAmount, ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 9 MONTH) = YEAR(billdate + INTERVAL 9 MONTH) THEN netamount ELSE 0 END)) as yearAmount , round(Sum(case when billdate >= date(now()) then netamount else 0 end)) as Transaction from  syncbill  where cancelled<>'Y' force index (ix_cancelled, ix_outlet),force INDEX (ix_outlet) FOR GROUP BY group by  OUTLET` this is the final query i have made by the suggestions you have given,but it is showing errors

Comment: If something is "showing errors", please share the error messages

Comment: could you please run the query split over multiple rows, so identifying where error is (using the row number) will be easier

Comment: @DDS i think i am making  some syntax errors, don't know where to put force index

Comment: @DDS i am writing both the indexces before the where and after the from clause,is this correct?

Comment: @viveksingh yes it is

Answer (score 1):

For improving the performance of new_Query, you should have one index on three Columns (cancelled, OUTLET) with this order that I write; because in the query execution, at first where expression executes then group by expression and at the end the select statement; if the index data pages were created with columns that used in this order, the speed of data seek is increased.

```
CREATE  INDEX ix_cancelled_OUTLET ON syncbill(cancelled, OUTLET);
```

Comment: can you help me like how can i write my query after creating index,or should i only run the previous one by creating index

Comment: Just you should create the index and run your own new_query that you have writen in the main post

Comment: can you please edit my query in main post, i am very much confused what to do

Comment: You don't need to change your query if you have one index on your table,first delete all indices of this table, and create ix_cancelled_OUTLET_billdate on it, after that run your own query, if this index is usefull for the query, the query optimizer choose that.

Comment: i have created the index you have suggested then ran my original query,but still it is taking 1 minute to fetch the data

Comment: Could you please attach the execution plan of the query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188210/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-sepna).